# Multiple DB connections and executor framework

Tags: multithreading, jdbc, java.util.concurrent, executor

I am working a project where we fetch a list of users who are accessing a DB, we are having around 250 servers and DB count might be around 1000. I am planning to use a connection pool using DBCP and Executor framework for multi-threading. Kindly suggest

Thanks in advance

Comment: I am looking for the best possible solution for the above mentioned question in short i need to connect to 250 servers and 1000 odd DB Oracle and SQL to run a stored procedure in each database and fetch the accounts

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by ExecutorCompletionService which will submit the tasks to a queue and use

ecs.take();

and process the result